# Problem with reference image - Changes to alpha does not change transparency

Tags: mesh, objects

I need to decrease the  reference image opacity, but when I decrease the      alpha in colour in Image tab (in properties), the image does not become transparent.

Image tab displaying the change in alpha
[image: Image tab displaying the change in alpha]

The reference image (a bowling pin), which is opaque, not transparent
[image: The reference image (a bowling pin), which is opaque, not transparent]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Change opacity in the data properties panel transparency subpanel**

[image]
*Change from object properties to data properties, set opacity*

The other answer popped up while making gif.  Thought I'd post as it is from a build of 2.83 and has a slightly different location for opacity setting.

Answer (score 3):

you have to go to the Object Data Properties, not the Object properties and there you can change the alpha. I'll show you in this image:

[image: instructions for image reference alpha]

Comment: This one no longer works in 2.83 :(

Answer (score 0):

As of 5/6/2022 for Blender version 3.1.2 the transparency option is still on the "Object Data Properties" tab but is now labeled "Opacity".

[image]